# How is it valid to use 'table.column=t.column' (when t is short for table)

Tags: mysql, sql

The code at the bottom works, which confuses me. I don't understand the expression:

```
where wands_property.age = p.age
```

because `p` is short hand for `wands_property`, so that expression seems to look like:

```
wands_property.age = wands_property.age
```

which is a tautology.

How is a table, `wands_property` different when it has been given an alias `p`?

CODE:

```
select w.id, p.age, w.coins_needed, w.power 
from wands w join wands_property p on w.code = p.code 
where p.is_evil = 0
and w.coins_needed = (
    select min(wands.coins_needed)
    from wands 
    join wands_property on wands.code = wands_property.code 
    where wands_property.age = p.age
    and wands.power = w.power)
order by power desc, age desc
```

Comment: Look up sub-queries, and then look up correlated sub-queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be less confusing of we assigned a unique alias to *all* table references, and qualified *all* column references with those aliases.

Here adding aliases `mp` and `mw` for the table references inside the correlated subquery:

```
SELECT w.id
     , p.age
     , w.coins_needed
     , w.power 
  FROM wands w 
  JOIN wands_property p 
    ON p.code = w.code 
 WHERE p.is_evil = 0
   AND w.coins_needed = 
       (
         SELECT MIN(mw.coins_needed)
           FROM wands mw  
           JOIN wands_property mp 
             ON mw.code  = mp.code 
          WHERE mp.age   = p.age
            AND mw.power = w.power
       )
ORDER
   BY w.power DESC
    , p.age DESC
```

Note that the references `p.age` and `w.power` in the subquery (inside the parens) are references to the tables *outside* the parens.  And `mw.` and `mp.` are references to the tables *inside* the parens.

The original query was fine, without the aliases, because it wasn't ambiguous (to MySQL) which tables were being referenced. We follow the pattern of giving unique aliases to all table references, and qualifying all column references, as an aid the human reader (and to avoid introducing "ambiguous column" errors when new columns are added to a table.)

---

If this doesn't clear up the confusion, then we need to gain an understanding of how a *correlated subquery* works.

For each row processed by the outer query, MySQL (in effect) runs the query inside the parens, substituting in the values for `p.age` and `w.power`, taking those values from the current row in the outer query.

Let's say the outer query is processing a row that has has values of 7 for p.age, and 42 for w.power

The subquery is effectively

```
         SELECT MIN(mw.coins_needed)
           FROM wands mw  
           JOIN wands_property mp 
             ON mw.code  = mp.code 
          WHERE mp.age   = 7
            AND mw.power = 42
```

We call it a *correlated* subquery because the references `p.age` and `w.power` inside the subquery are references to rows being processed in the outer query.  That is, the subquery is *related* to the current row being processed by the outer query.

Comment: Thanks Spencer, the example made it very clear. Btw, does that mean if you don't use an alias in the first place, this kind of query is impossible? I say this because if you didn't use an alias, it would be 'wands.power=wands.power'.

Comment: Yes. The original query would not be possible if there wasn't an alias on one of the references to the `wands` table. Without the alias, it wouldn't be possible to reference the `wands` table in the subquery, and also reference the `wands` table in the outer query. The "`wands.power=wands.power`" condition in the subquery would be reference to just the table in the subquery. Rendering that condition equivalent to "`wands.power IS NOT NULL`". The pattern I follow is assigning a unique alias to each table reference, and qualifying all column references with the table alias.

Answer (score 3):

The table alias `p`, which refers to a table in the outer query, and the table name `wands_property`, which is a table in the subquery, refer to different passes over what happens to be the same physical table, and therefore the expression may be comparing the column values of different rows within it.

It’s exactly the same as referring to completely different tables that have exactly the same schema and data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't get understand, could you explain that- what do you mean by different passes? Why would the rows it compares be different in each case? Would you be so kind as to use a real example say the example in my question, or your own tables? Like, what is happening in the above code with that part of the subquery? Thanks.

Comment: @tom when a table appears again in a query it is accessed afresh and is considered to be a completely different table within the query. It happens reasonably often in queries. I can’t explain it any more clearly than I have. Think about how you would return all combinations of names from a user table where the first letter was the same. Write the query yourself and when you’re done you will understand the concept.